# How to catch input from Python in bash script

Tags: python, bash

I am trying to pass several parameters from a python script to a bash script in the following way:

```
input_string = pathToScript + " " + input1 + " " + input2 + " " + input3 + " " + input4 + " " + \
input5 + " " + input6 + " "  + input7 + " " + input8 + " "  + input9 + " "  + input10

args =  shlex.split(input_string)

p = subprocess.Popen(args)
```

where all the `inputX` are strings. Each of these arguments shall be passed to the script, whose path is stored in the variable `pathToScript`. I now want to be able to catch these parameters in the bash script like I usually do:

```
#No input check yet...
history_file = "$1"
folder_history_file = "$2"
folder_bml_files = "$3"
separate_temperature = "$4"
separate_temperature_col_index = "$5"
separate_sight = "$6"
separate_sight_col_index = "$7"
separate_CO = "$8"
separate_CO_col_index = "$9"
separate_radiation = "$10"
```

This causes errors like `line 61: separate_CO_col_index: command not found` for all these lines and the errors do not appear in the same way the lines are ordered. In other words such error on line 61 is sometimes caught before the one on line 60, it seems from the output in Eclipse (I use PyDev in Eclipse).

Is it not possible to run the bash script like this? I have tried following the method in ch. 17.1.1.1 here, but I may not have understood it correctly: [python docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html)

Comment: First, look at using a list to store that data instead of 10 individually named variables.  Second, if you want to concatenate strings like that (which you shouldn't here anyway), use `join()`.  Third, if you put the data in a list, the concat>split to list>pass to arguments sequence becomes redundant (it's already wasteful, so you should just get rid of it).

Comment: Yeah, I'll definitely use a list, just tried a concatinated string to see if it made any difference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The errors in bash appear because you put spaces around the `=`. You should use

```
history_file="$1"
```

instead of

```
history_file = "$1"
```

When you put spaces there, Bash thinks the line is a command invocation and tries to run `history_file` as a command.

---

In your Python script, you can simply use:

```
args = [pathToScript, input1, input2, ....]
```

instead of what you have. This is simpler, and will work correctly if the arguments contain spaces, which your current code will fail on. There's no point in building the `input_string` string only to split it back in the following line.

Comment: Thank you, never realized that I didn't use whitespaces in my old scripts. The reason I concatinate the strings is just due to trial and error and this was my current try :)